# Backbone Fetch right after Save

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js

How do you call fetch right after save... I basically want to call a get directly after a successful post...

Here is the code attempt:

```
search: function (search) {
      searchM = new SearchM();

      searchM.save({
        channel: this.$('#channel').val(),
        week: this.$('#week').val(),
        year: this.$('#year').val(),
        filter: this.$('#filter').val()
      },
        {success: listStore()});

      function listStore () {
        console.log('list it');
        searchM.fetch({success: function (result) {
          console.log(result);
        }});
      }

    },
```

Comment: If you have access to the server-code, you could return a response from the server when you call `save`. Then you can access `result` from `save`'s `success` callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**

To get the response from the `.save` call, use the first parameter of the callback:

```
function listStore (model, response, options) {
    console.log(model.toJSON());
}
```

---

Your attempt looks about right, with one small mistake... the `success` callback should pass `listStore` without the parentheses:

```
searchM.save({ ... },
    { success: listStore });
```

This passes the *function* "listStore" as the callback.  When you include the parentheses, it runs `listStore` immediately, and the return value gets assigned as the callback (which of course does not make sense).

Comment: Ok I have made that change but the result is not logged to the console?

Comment: @Lion789 but "list it" does get logged?  If so, I wonder if there's some problem with your server, or the Ajax call itself.  Do you see the "fetch" network call being made in Firebug?

Comment: List it does get logged, I am looking at network tab in chrome... and for the post the response does come back with the correct information but there is a get right after it... to the same url which then has a response of just the page without the response from the post...

Comment: @Lion789 the Get is the one to examine ... it sounds like the URL is correct, which means that it's the servers fault.  It should be returning JSON content for the item, so why is it returning the page content?

Comment: I am getting back JSON, but why is it doing a GET for the page after? On the server side I have it responding with the item as json and it is not calling a get to the page... Do you know what could be calling a get to the page, because if fetch is not being called is it because after the save call it is refreshing the page or something?

Comment: Let me clear up something that might have not been mentioned ... when I call save and make the POST I am using that POST to make a callback on the server-side for a data that is a one time transfer, meaning after the POST I am calling res.json right away sending the result... so it has to be received then otherwise it will be lost...

Comment: correct, so instead of a get then, I need to actually get the response from the POST instead of calling a get then like that? How would I go about that then?

Comment: @Lion789 if you add parameters to `listStore`, that should give you waht you need.  The first parameter it gets is the Backbone model that just got saved.  http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save